# How do I integrate tabs into android preference

Tags: android, tabs, android-preferences

I want to have a List Preference with 3 tabs (3 lists) inside it. I think none of android default preference (ListPreference, CheckBoxPreference, RingtonePreference etc.) supports tabs. I think I will need to write a custom preference for this. 
I know for writing tabs you need to extend TabActivity but I am not getting how to do it for custom preference. Please help?

I need something like a CustomListPreference which contains 3 tabs each containing a list of options. User can select one item out of these 3 lists. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a Tabbed view (extending `TabActivity`) in which each of your tab activity is a `PreferenceActivity`.